# How to jump to 0 index of array if it will be exceeded in java?

Tags: java, math, calculation

Let's say that i have an array of int's in range 65-90. I'll randomly pick one of elements and add 10 to it. Is it possible that value, if cross range of 90 return to 65? For example - i take a 85 and add 10 to it. So it should be 95, but i  want a 70.

Comment: what should be the result be when the sum is 90? 65 or 90?

Comment: think 90 will do work. But smart notice :)

Comment: so 91->65, 92->66, 93->67, 94->68, **95 -> 69** not 70, or? (seems much like working with characters 'A' through 'Z')

Comment: doing caesar cipher without working with bits (At least on code level :p). Have same with 97-122 : )

Comment: @Quander can you answer Carlos' question about 69 vs 70? My answer actually returned 69 originally but I thought I had made an off-by-one mistake and modified it. Now my answer returns 70 but is clearly logically incorrect. What is the correct expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by placing your value in the interval `[0, high - low]` by removing `low` to your value, then add the number you want to it, take the modulo of the sum, and finally add `low` back to get back in the range `[low, high]`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int low = 65, high = 90;
    System.out.println(addWithinInterval(85, 10, low, high));
}

private static int addWithinInterval(int value, int add, int low, int high) {
    return (value - low + add) % (high - low + 1) + low;
}
```

Comment: `... % (high - low + 1) ...` at least that code is returning `low` when `value = high; add = 0` so the range is not including `high` [math: `x % (high-low) + low` never returns `high` (assuming `high` greater than `low`)]

Comment: Yeah right, let me review this. I did have `+ 1` at the beginning but I didn't have the expected result in some cases.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger edited. I think what I had at the beginning was right, it's the expectation of getting 70 that wasn't correct. 69 is the correct answer. Eventually it depends from what the OP considers right but I think this makes more sense this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll randomly pick one of elements and add 10 to it. Is it possible that value, if cross range of 90 return to 65?

Sure, the remainder operator will do that for you:

```
n = (n - 65) % (90 - 65) + 65;
```

Example ([live copy](https://ideone.com/YrXUMD)):

```
int n = 85;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    n += 10;
    n = (n - 65) % (90 - 65) + 65;
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Or here on site: Java and JavaScript are different, but their `%` operators work the same, so:

```js
let n = 85;
for (let x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
  n += 10;
  n = (n - 65) % (90 - 65) + 65;
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Just a note, for @Quander: if eventually this is to be ASCII, in Java you can simple write `'A'` instead of 65, and `'Z'` instead of 90 since in Java chars are also integer numbers (`char`, not `int`, but convertible)

Comment: Note to above code: I think it must be `... % (90 - 65 + 1) ...`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - No, the code above is correct. And yes, you can do that if that's what the OP wants (it's not ASCII, though -- well, in the range 65-90 it's *also* ASCII, but Java uses Unicode, specifically UTF-16). They didn't mention using characters, so I didn't go there. :-)

Comment: ok, then @Quander, if this eventually should be for characters between `A` and `Z`, then you can/should use `(char) ( (n - 'A') % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A')`